# P5.js Draw() function not working as expected in AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, p5.js

I'm trying to integrate the p5.js library in my AngularJS application, having my code run in a directive.

In my plain JavaScript files, Im able to run the draw() method after importing the p5 library globally.

### My original code (not the issue):

```
var mic
var playButton
var volHistory = []
var micIsOn = false

function setup(){
    createCanvas(400, 150)
    createButtons()
    mic = new p5.AudioIn()
}

function draw(){
    background(245)
    stroke(0, 109, 203) 

    //populate volHistory
    if(micIsOn){
        var vol = mic.getLevel()
        //check to see if array is empty, if it is empty we do not want to push 0 volume
        if(volHistory.length > 0 && vol > 0){
            volHistory.push(vol)
        //if recording has started, we can now take in vol
        } else if(vol > 0) {
            volHistory.push(vol)
            console.log(volHistory.length)
        }
    }

    //iterate through volHistory and draw
    fill(0, 109, 203)
    var barWidth = 2;
    var offsetWidth = 5;
    var offset = 5;
    for(var i = 0; i < volHistory.length; i++){
        var barHeight = map(volHistory[i], 0, 1, 1, height)
        rect(i + offset, (height/2.0) - (barHeight/2.0), barWidth, barHeight, 15);
        offset += offsetWidth;
    }

    //moves wavelength 1 index at a time and account for bar width and offset width
    if(volHistory.length * (offsetWidth + barWidth) > width){
        volHistory.splice(0, 1)
    }

    //draw vertical line
    stroke(250, 30, 100)
    line(volHistory.length + offset, 0, volHistory.length + offset, height) 
}

function createButtons(){
    playButton = createButton("<img style='width: 50px' src='playbutton.png'/>")
    playButton.mousePressed(toggleRecord)
    playButton.position(162, 50)
    playButton.style("background-color", color(0,0,0,0))
    playButton.style("border", 0)
}

//toggle recording of audio
function toggleRecord(){
    if(!micIsOn){
        mic.start()
        micIsOn = true
    } else {
        mic.stop()
        micIsOn = false
    }
}
```

The code above lets me create a sound-visualizer, that taps into the mic of the user, drawing a canvas that displays the level of their sound. Looking like this:
[image]

However, when I try to use the library in my Angular directive, I cannot seem to get the draw() method to function as expected. The draw() function does not run continuously like it would outside an Angular directive.

The closest I've gotten to get this to work is by creating a `$watch` on a variable to track whether the user isRecording. If isRecording is true I would use a setInterval to call draw() continuously. Unfortunately, this appears to an improper usage of the draw() method, since its supposed to execute the code inside it continuously on its own after the first execution.

### Angular code:

```
(function () {

    angular.module('icSdkPwp').directive('icAudioRecordingUpload', icAudioRecordingUpload);

    function icAudioRecordingUpload($stateSvc, $rS, $utilSvc) {
        return {
            scope: {
                model: '=',
                config: '=',
                updateState: '='
            },
            link: function ($s, e, a) {

                $s.hasRecording = false;
                $s.isRecording = false;
                $s.recordingPaused = false;
                $s.recordingProcessing = false;
                $s.volHistory = []
                $s.micIsOn = false
                $s.p5mic = null
                $s.playButton = null

            var gumStream;
            var rec;
            var input;

            var AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
            var audioContext
```

```
            $s.startRecording = function(e) {
                if($s.recordingProcessing)
                    return;

                var constraints = { audio: true, video:false }
                setup()
                $s.isRecording = true;

                navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
                  .then(function(stream) {
                    audioContext = new AudioContext();
                    gumStream = stream;
                    input = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
                    rec = new Recorder(input,{numChannels:2})
                    rec.record()

                }).catch(function(err) {
                    $s.isRecording = true;
                });
            }

           var redrawInt = null;
           $s.$watch("isRecording", function (n, o, s) {
                if(s.isRecording){
                    redrawInt = setInterval(function(){
                        draw()
                    },0);
                }
                else{
                    clearInterval(redrawInt);
                }

            });


            function setup(){
                createCanvas(400, 150)
                $s.p5mic = new p5.AudioIn()
                $s.p5mic.start()
                $s.micIsOn = true
                background(245)
            }

            function draw(){
                stroke(0, 109, 203) 

                //populate volHistory
                if($s.isRecording){
                    var vol = $s.p5mic.getLevel()
                    //check to see if array is empty, if it is empty we do not want to push 0 volume
                    if($s.volHistory.length > 0 && vol > 0){
                    $s.volHistory.push(vol)
                    //if recording has started, we can now take in vol
                    } else if(vol > 0) {
                        $s.volHistory.push(vol)
                    }
                }

                //iterate through volHistory and draw
                fill(0, 109, 203)
                var barWidth = 2;
                var offsetWidth = 5;
                var offset = 5;
                for(var i = 0; i < $s.volHistory.length; i++){
                    var barHeight = map($s.volHistory[i], 0, 1, 1, height)
                    rect(i + offset, (height/2.0) - (barHeight/2.0), barWidth, barHeight, 15);
                    offset += offsetWidth;
                }

                    //moves wavelength 1 index at a time and account for bar width and offset width
                if($s.volHistory.length * (offsetWidth + barWidth) > width){
                    $s.volHistory.splice(0, 1)
                }

                    //draw vertical line
                stroke(250, 30, 100)
                // debugger
                line($s.volHistory.length + offset, 0, $s.volHistory.length + offset, height) 
            }

        }
        };
    }

}());
```

### Button that calls startRecording(), initiating the process

```
<div class="IX_recordControls clearfix">
    <div class="rcrow row1">
        <div ng-click="recordingProcessing || startRecording($event)"
             ng-if="!hasRecording">
    </div>
</div>
```

This gives me a really bizarre canvas, which I suppose is expected since I shouldn't be calling draw() so many times, but I cannot find a way to make it call a single time and run continuously.

[image]

This definitely looks like a problem with scope, where the draw() method is unable to execute its own loop.

Comment: The directive is creating a new isolate scope that does not inherit from its parent. I don't see how it invokes the `startRecording` function`

Comment: @georgeawg. Thanks for the edit and feedback. I totally forgot to post the HTML with the click-event that calls startRecording. Just added that now. Please let me know if you have any thoughts on how I can better execute this.